# Why sklearn GBDT target value can't be float?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My python code:

```
y_train = y_train.astype(float)
X_train = X_train.astype(float)
kernel = gbdt()
kernel = gbdt()
kernel.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

The error is `ValueError: Unknown label type: array([ 0.0206, -0.006 ,  0.0008, ...,  0.0245,  0.0166, -0.022 ], dtype=float32).`

In sklearn gbdt document, it says: Target values (integers in classification, **real numbers in regression**) For classification, labels must correspond to classes.

Any one knows what happened?

Comment: could you provide links to the documentation? which class do you use? It seems like you use the [classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier), which will fail for your data. But maybe the documentation can be improved here.

Comment: Yes, your link is the document i have looked up.

Comment: Obviously you are using the classifier, which only accepts integer class labels.  So, if you want to do regression you need to use the regressor class, which you can find in the API description. Otherwise, you should convert the class labels to ints.

Comment: Thank you and i will use the regressor instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two GBDT algorithms in sklearn ensemble,
**ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier** and 
**ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor**
and you are expected to specify which algorithm fits your task best.

For regression, take GradientBoostingRegressor, GradientBoostingClassifier for classification.
For example,

```
gbdt=GradientBoostingRegressor(
  loss='ls'
, learning_rate=0.1
, n_estimators=100
, subsample=1
, min_samples_split=2
, min_samples_leaf=1
, max_depth=3
, init=None
, random_state=None
, max_features=None
, alpha=0.9
, verbose=0
, max_leaf_nodes=None
, warm_start=False
)

gbdt.fit(X, y)
```

It seems that you are doing regression since your responses do not like categorical values, so you may try GradientBoostingRegressor()